# redux framework: add custom css to the output css

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add a border radius from a normal text field to the outputted css of redux framework.

Unfortunately normal text fields don´t support the output argument.

How can I add my custom css to the css created by redux?

Answer (score 0):

Will answer this as a general CSS/webdev question, since I don't know Redux:

Either make your own CSS file with the code you want and load that in the same files as where the Redux CSS is used, making sure to override the Redux code where necessary, or use an already loaded CSS file. :)

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn´t help me as I want to do it the "redux" way ;)

Comment: Well then, perhaps you'll find your answer here? :) 
https://docs.reduxframework.com/extensions/css-layout/

Comment: I know this page, but it´s an extension I don´t want to buy just for one css style

Comment: Well, then it seems to me you either have to do "post Redux", like I mentioned above, or write your own plugin for it.